# XCode5 says missing SDK 10.7, but I only refer to 10.8

Tags: macos, sdk, xcode5

I just installed OS X 10.8 and XCode 5 and I am trying to build a project. I changed the base SDK and Deployment target both to 10.8 and I get this error.
I can't find any reference to 10.7 in my settings, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Xcode typically only ships with one SDK for each platform (e.g. Xcode 5 supports iOS 7 & MacOS 10.9 SDK; and at this precise moment it also has MacOS 10.8's SDK built in but probably not for much longer), so in my own settings I typically refer to "Latest SDK" (whichever is shipping with the installed version of Xcode).

And then you can reset "minimum deployment version" in your project settings to be the actual minimum MacOS version (10.5, 10.6, 10.7) you want to run on.

Now, if you do NOT see references to "10.7" in your settings, you may need to actually look at the raw XML of your "project.pbxproj" which resides within your Xcode project.  You can look at it in a text editor and see if it's referring to 10.7 anywhere unexpected within it.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Yes, I found two references to 10.7 in that file. They were in the build settings for the Debug and Release versions. "SDKROOT = "$(DEVELOPER_SDK_DIR)/MacOSX10.7.sdk";
Why can't I find that entry when I look at build settings in Xcode?

Comment: It does build now, Thanks!